# Why i can't add actionListener written in other file

Tags: java, swing

I have an ActionListener in other file & i want to use that ActionListener in my gui code which is

```
package GUI;

public class CheckButtonGUI {

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton One, Two, Three, Four;
    JLabel buttonStatus;

    public JPanel getGUI()
    {
        CheckButtonGUI cbg = new CheckButtonGUI();
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
        One = new JButton("1");
        Two = new JButton("2");
        Three = new JButton("3");
        Four = new JButton("4");
        buttonStatus = new JLabel("No Button Pressed");

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(One,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        //gbc.gridy = 0;
        mainPanel.add(Two,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(Three,gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        mainPanel.add(Four,gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth=3;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        mainPanel.add(buttonStatus,gbc);

        // Action Listeners
        CheckListener cli = new CheckListener(this);
        One.addActionListener(cli);
        Two.addActionListener(cli);
        Three.addActionListener(cli);
        Four.addActionListener(cli);


        return mainPanel;
    }
    public void displayText(String str)
    {
        buttonStatus.setText(str);
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JTextField of Dreams [=]");

        CheckButtonGUI demo = new CheckButtonGUI();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.getGUI());
        frame.setLocation(550, 350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // We no longer manually re-size, we use pack to automatically size the frame.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }   
});
    }

}
```

each & everything works fine but as soon as i try to add actionListener, the ECLIPSE IDE shows error. if i put null, error removes but then compiler doesn't work. i don't understand what i am doing wrong... Following is my actionListener, in case you need more details

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CheckListener implements ActionListener
{
    //private ButtoncheckGUI bcg;
    private CheckButtonGUI cbg;

    public CheckListener(ButtoncheckGUI b)
    {
        //bcg = b;
        cbg = b;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
    {
        String op = action.getActionCommand();
        if(op.equals("1"))
        {
            cbg.displayText("Button 1 was Pressed");
        }else if (op.equals("2"))
        {
            cbg.displayText("Button 2 was Pressed");
        }else if (op.equals("3"))
        {
            cbg.displayText("Button 3 was Pressed");
        }else if (op.equals("4"))
        {
            cbg.displayText("Button 4 was Pressed");
        }else 
        {
            cbg.displayText("unExpected Input");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You give the code for `CheckListener` but you don't reference it anywhere else in your code.  Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @user489041 I changed it but it is actionListener that i want to access whenever putton is pressed.

Comment: @whiskeyspider Please see the rectified code. I can use the same file in other GUI model(//private ButtoncheckGUI bcg) but when i implement same approach for this gui model(private CheckButtonGUI cbg) it shows error. In other model, i referenced same actionListener with same approach but i don't know what's problem here.
One thing i must mention is that: In other gui model i return panel with this i.e. return this but here i do i.e. return mainPanel. Rest of code is same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error was in actionListener's constructor's Parameter. i,somehow wrongly, instantiated actionListner's constructor with wrong 'gui model' object. As you can see, in my Controller class i.e. actionlistener there is ButtoncheckGUI b instantiated rather than CheckButtonGui b. Replaceing 'ButtoncheckGUI' with CheckButtonGUI resolved the issue!